# Finding suggested flight destinations from database in Golang

Tags: go

This is my first Go project. Coming from a Java developer background, this code just smells very bad. But, cannot figure out better way to do this.

It's a small app to find suggested flight destinations based on one or more origins (by their airport-codes, called `codes`below). 
Basically finding flights that have the same destination and about the same arrival times.

```
// SuggestDestinations takes a list of origin airport codes, an earliest arrival time and a latest arrival time and
// returns a map, where the destination is the key, and the suggested flights.
func (service *FlightService) SuggestDestinations(codes []string, earliestArrival, latestArrival time.Time) (destinationMap map[string][]internal.Flight, err error) {
    rows, err := service.db.Query(selectFlightsSQL, pq.Array(codes), earliestArrival, latestArrival)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    var m map[string][]internal.Flight
    m = make(map[string][]internal.Flight)
    for rows.Next() {
        var a internal.Flight
        var origin, destination, airline string
        if e := rows.Scan(&origin, &destination, &airline, &a.Departure, &a.Arrival); err != nil {
            return nil, e
        }
        a.Origin, err = service.GetAirport(origin)
        a.Destination, err = service.GetAirport(destination)
        a.Airline, err = service.GetAirline(airline)
        // Filter out destinations which is one of the origins
        if !contains(codes, a.Destination.Code) {
            m[a.Destination.Code] = append(m[a.Destination.Code], a)
        }
    }

    // Delete destinations for which there are not flights from every given origin
    for k := range m {
        if !containsAllCodes(m[k], codes) {
            delete(m, k)
        }
    }

    return m, nil
}
```

Where containsAllCodes looks like this:

```
func containsAllCodes(flights []internal.Flight, codes []string) bool {
containsAllOrigin := true
for _, c := range codes {
    containsOrigin := false
    for _, f := range flights {
        containsOrigin = containsOrigin || f.Origin.Code == c
    }
    containsAllOrigin = containsAllOrigin && containsOrigin
    }
    return containsAllOrigin
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... this code just smells very bad. But, cannot figure out better way
>   to do this.

Let's look at a more complete, more fragrant implementation.

---

For data, you are using PostgreSQL: `db.Query(selectFlightsSQL, pq.Array(codes), ...)`. Therefore, define data using the SQL Data Definition Language (DDL). For example,

```
CREATE TABLE airlines (
    airlinecode char(3) NOT NULL,
    airlinename varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (airlinecode),
    UNIQUE (airlinename)
);

CREATE TABLE airports (
    airportcode char(3) NOT NULL,
    airportname varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    timezonename varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (airportcode),
    UNIQUE (airportname)
);

CREATE TABLE flights (
    airlinecode char(3) NOT NULL,
    flightno integer NOT NULL,
    departtime timestamptz NOT NULL, -- local time
    origincode char(3) NOT NULL,
    arrivetime timestamptz NOT NULL, -- local time
    destinationcode char(3) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (airlinecode, flightno, departtime),
    FOREIGN KEY (airlinecode) REFERENCES airlines,
    FOREIGN KEY (origincode) REFERENCES airports,
    FOREIGN KEY (destinationcode) REFERENCES airports
);
```

Access the data using the SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML). For example,

```
    -- $1  origincode list
    -- $2  origincode list length
    -- $3  earliest arrivaltime
    -- $4  latest arrivaltime
    SELECT destinationcode, airportd.airportname AS destinationname, arrivetime, airportd.timezonename AS arrivezone,
        origincode, airporto.airportname AS originname, departtime, airporto.timezonename AS departzone,
        destinations.airlinecode, airlines.airlinename, flightno

    FROM (

        SELECT destinationcode, origincode, airlinecode, flightno, departtime, arrivetime,
            count(origincode) OVER (PARTITION BY destinationcode) AS origins
        FROM flights
        WHERE arrivetime >= $3 AND arrivetime <= $4
            AND origincode = ANY($1)
            AND destinationcode != ANY($1)

    ) AS destinations 
    LEFT JOIN airlines ON airlines.airlinecode = destinations.airlinecode
    LEFT JOIN airports AS airportd ON airportd.airportcode = destinationcode
    LEFT JOIN airports AS airporto ON airporto.airportcode = origincode

    WHERE origins = $2 

    ORDER BY destinationcode, arrivetime, airlinecode, flightno, departtime
    ;
```

Consider optimizations such as indices.

Data access is implemented in SQL for any programming language that implements an interface to PostgreSQL (and other relational DBMS`s), not just Go.

---

In Go, the remaining algorithmic, procedural task is simple: convert the SQL rows to a Go hash map indexed by destination code. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "time"

    "github.com/lib/pq"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

type Flight struct {
    DestinationCode string
    DestinationName string
    ArriveTime      time.Time
    ArriveZone      string
    OriginCode      string
    OriginName      string
    DepartTime      time.Time
    DepartZone      string
    AirlineCode     string
    AirlineName     string
    FlightNo        int
}

func destinations(db *sql.DB, origins []string, earliest, latest time.Time) (map[string][]Flight, error) {
    query := `
        -- $1  origincode list
        -- $2  origincode list length
        -- $3  earliest arrivaltime
        -- $4  latest arrivaltime
       SELECT destinationcode, airportd.airportname AS destinationname, arrivetime, airportd.timezonename AS arrivezone,
            origincode, airporto.airportname AS originname, departtime, airporto.timezonename AS departzone,
            destinations.airlinecode, airlines.airlinename, flightno

        FROM (

            SELECT destinationcode, origincode, airlinecode, flightno, departtime, arrivetime,
                count(origincode) OVER (PARTITION BY destinationcode) AS origins
            FROM flights
            WHERE arrivetime >= $3 AND arrivetime <= $4
                AND origincode = ANY($1)
                AND destinationcode != ANY($1)

        ) AS destinations 
        LEFT JOIN airlines ON airlines.airlinecode = destinations.airlinecode
        LEFT JOIN airports AS airportd ON airportd.airportcode = destinationcode
        LEFT JOIN airports AS airporto ON airporto.airportcode = origincode

        WHERE origins = $2 

        ORDER BY destinationcode, arrivetime, airlinecode, flightno, departtime
        ;
        `

    dst := make(map[string][]Flight)
    rows, err := db.Query(query, pq.Array(origins), len(origins), earliest, latest)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    for rows.Next() {
        var flt Flight
        err := rows.Scan(
            &flt.DestinationCode,
            &flt.DestinationName,
            &flt.ArriveTime,
            &flt.ArriveZone,
            &flt.OriginCode,
            &flt.OriginName,
            &flt.DepartTime,
            &flt.DepartZone,
            &flt.AirlineCode,
            &flt.AirlineName,
            &flt.FlightNo,
        )
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        dst[flt.DestinationCode] = append(dst[flt.DestinationCode], flt)
    }
    err = rows.Err()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return dst, nil
}

func main() {}
```

---

The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem: [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Therefore, without a problem, we have no way of knowing whether a solution is correct. There are no use cases or examples.

---

TODO: Domain knowledge is important. Airline arrival and departure times are local times. Any solution needs to be verified and tested across time zones and for standard and daylight saving times.